# Failed 2008 server with Raid Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, dell-poweredge, dell

I have a customer who called us with a failed server. I believe the issue is either the motherboard or the power supply (This happened after a power outage). The server is an old 2008 server which they do not want to replace. They just want the data.

The server appears to have been in a raid with a dell raid controller.

They have no details on the type of raid configuration, as the person who managed it left years ago.

The server had 3 drives in it.

1. 250 GB with 4 partitions. A 41MB fat 32 partition, a 16GB partition 2 labeled ddf_raid_member, a 64gb ddf_raid_member, a 419gb extended partition, and  419gb free space. Not sure how this is possible as it is labeled a 250GB drive.
2. 250 GB of a single partition. Unbuntu says it is a DDF_RAID_MEMBER, but windows says its unallocated space when hooked up via sata adapter
3. Appears to be a copy of disk 1. All same names and sizes.

My question is - Is there a way to view/recover this data without having to order a new motherboard and power supply for the server?

I cloned one of the drives and tried to do a recover my fails scan but only found a few thousand LOST_FILE_EXEs.

The server is a dell poweredge older model I believe 2950.

dell raid controller but no other markings I can tell.

The issue shows

e122A and e1224

power voltage issues the dell site says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server using RAID Controller hardware, please check the RAID Controller Battery, I was found this problem in my office after power outage few months ago, so I just ordered a used RAID Controller battery form ebay, this is much cheaper than buying a new motherboard.